# Django 2.0.9 - MultiSelectFormField - Parâmetro para tornar não obrigatório

Tags: django, django-2.0

Quero tornar o campo **MultiSelectField** não obrigatório. Quando não escolho nenhuma das opções a validação está acusando **campo obrigatório**. Já tentei utilizar os parâmetros blank=True e null=True, porém ainda continua acusando que o campo é obrigatório.

Alguém conhece qual parâmetro devo informar para o campo **MultiSelectField** ser opcional e não obrigatório?

forms.py

```
    class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

        MY_CHOICES = (
            ('1', "A good choice"),
            ('2', "A bad choice"),
        )

        my_field = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
               label='Escolhas', widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=MY_CHOICE
               )
```

models.py

```
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    MY_CHOICES = (
        ('1', "A good choice"),
        ('2', "A bad choice"),
    )
    my_field = MultiSelectField('Escolhas', choices=MY_CHOICES, default=0)
```

Comment: Gabriel, o título da sua pergunta especifica que é [tag:django-2.0], mas você colocou a tag [tag:django-1.8]. Você poderia esclarecer qual dos dois é o que você está usando??

Comment: Mudei aqui kkkk. Estou utilizando a versão do Django 2.0.9

Answer (score 0):

Cara, na [documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/) não tem nenhum MultiSelectField, então suponho que você está usando [django-multiselectfield](https://github.com/goinnn/django-multiselectfield/tree/v0.1.8) (seria legal especificar na pergunta a lib e a versão).

Vendo [o código](https://github.com/goinnn/django-multiselectfield/blob/v0.1.8/multiselectfield/db/fields.py#L62), dá pra perceber que a classe extende de `models.CharField` e usa os campos separados por vírgula por debaixo dos panos. Também dá para perceber que ela implementa as propriedades `min_choices` e `max_choices`.

Nunca usei esta biblioteca, mas tentaria utilizar `blank=True` e `min_choices=0`.

Ex.:

```
my_field = MultiSelectField('Escolhas', choices=MY_CHOICES, blank=True, min_choices=0)
```

Comment: Estou utilizando a lib django-multiselectfield, desculpe por não especificar a versão da lib, nem sei como vejo isso. Faz sentido o que disse, vou tentar fazer e dou retorno. Obrigado!

Comment: É apenas uma recomendação para que sua pergunta tenha mais qualidade. Perguntas com mais qualidade tendem a ter respostas melhores. A minha, por exemplo, está passível de levar uns _downvotes_ por ser vaga. Mas como não trabalhei com a biblioteca é meu limite no que posso ajudar. :D

Comment: blank=True, min_choices=0 não funcionou, porém coloquei required=False e o campo não é mais obrigatório. Value!